# Great delay in response time in mongoose/mongoDB as api is called consecutively over time (irrespective of collection size)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, response, latency

I have a simple api using the mongoose find method, along with an _id filter:

```
Fee.find(
  {
    _id: feeDocId,
  },
  (err, fee) => {
    if (fee[0] !== undefined) {
      if (!err && fee[0] != '') {
        res.json(fee[0]['gstno']);
      }
    }
  }
);
```

The problem is that the response time of this api keeps on increasing exponentially with time (high latency).

| API call | Latency (response time) |
| --- | --- |
| First time | 68ms |
| Third time | 22.75 sec |
| Fifth time | 55.18 sec |
| Seventh time | 1.6 minutes |
| ninth time | 2.3 minutes |

```
fired at api 2022-05-11T12:45:03+05:30 {}
response at api{
  explainVersion: '1',
  queryPlanner: {
    namespace: 'myFirstDatabase.fee',
    indexFilterSet: false,
    parsedQuery: { _id: [Object] },
    maxIndexedOrSolutionsReached: false,
    maxIndexedAndSolutionsReached: false,
    maxScansToExplodeReached: false,
    winningPlan: { stage: 'IDHACK' },
    rejectedPlans: []
  },
  executionStats: {
    executionSuccess: true,
    nReturned: 1,
    executionTimeMillis: 1,
    totalKeysExamined: 1,
    totalDocsExamined: 1,
    executionStages: {
      stage: 'IDHACK',
      nReturned: 1,
      executionTimeMillisEstimate: 0,
      works: 2,
      advanced: 1,
      needTime: 0,
      needYield: 0,
      saveState: 0,
      restoreState: 0,
      isEOF: 1,
      keysExamined: 1,
      docsExamined: 1
    },
    allPlansExecution: []
  },
  command: {
    find: 'fee',
    filter: { _id: new ObjectId("623042ce5fc371ac74c9b371") },
    projection: {},
    '$db': 'myFirstDatabase'
  },
 
}
response at  api  2022-05-11T12:48:41+05:30
API took this much time 217829
```

Any ideas as to why the latency increases progressively?

An important note: this high latency trend also applies to all other apis, and the trend repeats when I restart the server, ie, the response time increases over time since server start.The server being used is the M0 Sandbox (General) in MongoDB.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please add a sample of your documents

Comment: Can you estimate network latency using `ping`, `hping`, etc.?

Comment: @nimrodserok by documents you mean the entire server side code? Thanks for your response..

Comment: No, I mean 3 documents from your db. Each 'row' on a mongodb is called a document.

Comment: @rickhg12hs i am still new to node js, so i dont really know how to use the hping library. But i assure you, that the response times i have shown are correct as i have taken them from the google developer console and postman..

Comment: @nimrodserok here is the sample of the document for the api mentioned above:

There is only one document in this particular collection.

[ { _id:623042ce5fc371ac74c9b371, coord:"40”, referrer:"15”, centre:"15”, gstno:"ghhhj”, totalrev:4720, healer:"30”,
  shares:Object}]

I tried uploading the screenshot but couldn't do it.

Comment: You have only one document and it is taking 2.3 minutes to get it?

Comment: @nimrodserok yess....and thats not all, by the time i call this api tenth or eleventh time, the the response time goes upto 8 minutes!! this trend is uniform across all apis btw...irrespective of the number of documents

Comment: I don't know what can cause this, but I suggest you will add the information that you have only one small document to the title of the question

Comment: This will draw-in people who know how to help :)

Comment: If you look at `tshark -t d -f 'host whatever_your_mongodb_server_name_is'`, do the delta times displayed correspond to your latency measurements?  If so, then your local system probably isn't causing the latency.  If the times are different, then something locally may be "holding"/"delaying" the communications.